# what is the difference between the functions getAddUrl and getAddToCartUrl?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

I have found two function returning the exactly same value.

`getAddUrl` in `\app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php`

`getAddToCartUrl` in `\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php`

what is really the difference between these two, as I am adding an add to cart button in my block.
Which function should I use to add the product to the cart ?

Comment: I think that the code explains everything. Just take a look in the files you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code under `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` has a very useful comment.

```
/**
 * Retrieve url for add product to cart
 * Will return product view page URL if product has required options
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param array $additional
 * @return string
 */
public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    if ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
        if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
            $additional['_escape'] = true;
        }
        if (!isset($additional['_query'])) {
            $additional['_query'] = array();
        }
        $additional['_query']['options'] = 'cart';

        return $this->getProductUrl($product, $additional);
    }
    return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

The difference is that the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getAddToCartUrl` will set the url as the product view page if the product has required options, otherwise it will just return `Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::getAddUrl`.

The `getAddToCartUrl` can be used when you are not on the product view page, say for the wishlist page. So that you do not get an error when the user tries to add a product to the cart that has required options.